# How to add log4j to a web application that use OSGI bundle

Tags: java, maven, log4j, osgi

I am trying to add log4j library to record the exchange between client-server to a web application that I created which is a hello world application .

So I used the following tutorial to create this app  [1]: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-osgiservice-cdi.html

Now I want to add log4j but the problem that I don't know where to add it in **MavenHelloServiceApi** , in **MavenHelloServiceImpl** or in **MavenHelloWebClient**

Comment: This question is very vague. You should try to rephrase the question. If you want to log messages , you should add them in both the web client as  well as the Backend api bundle, i.e MavenHelloServiceImpl.

Answer (score 0):

You should add log4j dependency in every bundle you are going to use it.